# NPM not responding after installing new version of Node

Tags: node.js, npm

In Windows I installed nvm using an installer and then used nvm install to install node 6.5.0.

node -v shows v6.5.0

However npm install, even npm -v or any npm command do not return anything.

> npm -v

It just jumps to the next line instantaneously.
What might be causing this?

Uninstalling all previously installed versions of node from Control Panel
Reinstall nvm and start over.
Restart the computer